# User Specific Folder access to S3

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3, mean-stack, pre-signed-url

I have an application where users upload their documents-(let's say some of the documents are sensitive documents like ID Proofs). My S3 bucket structure is such that each user has its own folder inside which his/her documents are saved.

The application runs on the MEAN stack.

As of now the bucket is public. (Sensitive Documents uploading is a future addition).

I want the logged in user to be able to access only his/her documents. Also, the document URL should be secured. (Pre-Signed URL maybe)

What should be my approach for the above requirement? Any code resources/docs etc..?

Comment: How does your application allow users to access documents? Does it issue them temporary credentials via [AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html) and they use those credentials in the client or browser to access content from S3, _OR_ does your application simply provide links to content from S3 without issuing temporary STS credentials?

Comment: My application stores document urls in MongoDb collection. And, no it doesn't use AWS Secuirty Token Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **should not use any Bucket Policies**. The bucket should be kept 'private' and access should be granted to end-users in one of two ways:

**Option 1: Providing temporary AWS Credentials**

Where there is a 'smart' client (eg mobile app or JavaScript in browser), your back-end can **generate temporary credentials** using the [AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html). The client can then use these credentials to talk directly with AWS services, such as accessing objects in Amazon S3 and reading/writing data in DynamoDB.

The **back-end** is responsible for authenticating the user, generating the temporary credentials and passing them to the client, but is *not* involved in the subsequent calls to AWS. **Policies** can be attached to these temporary credentials to give permissions such as "Permit GetObject from this particular sub-directory (Path) of this Amazon S3 bucket".

If each user has a policy that only grants access to 'their sub-directory', then this meets your requirement that they can **only access their specific documents**.

A common way of implementing the above is to use **Amazon Cognito** for authentication and assigning permissions.

**Option 2: Using Pre-signed URLs**

In situations where the clients are **simple web pages** that do *not* directly use AWS credentials to call AWS services, the security is handled in the back-end using pre-signed URLs.

When the back-end is generating a web page that links to a private object (eg via `<img src='...'>`), the back-end should:

- Verify that the user is entitled to access the private object
- Generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object
- Insert that URL into the HTML page, or provide it as a link (eg to a PDF)
- When the user's browser uses the URL to request the object from S3, the S3 service will verify the signature to confirm that the user is entitled to access the private object and the expiry time has not passed
- If the signature is confirmed, S3 will pass back the private object

This method **gives the back-end full control over *which* objects in S3 the user can access**. It could maintain this list in a database, or it could rely on the path of the object to determine this access. This can even be extended to **permit sharing objects between users**. For example, imagine a photo-sharing application where a user wants to share a photo with another user. They could indicate this through the UI and the back-end could store this in a database. Later, when a user wants to view a shared photo, the back-end would check the database to confirm their entitlement, then generate a pre-signed URL to view the shared object, even though it is in a different path.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the detailed answer. I think option 1 would be a better option for my use-case as I don't want the URLs to expire and I want the user to be able to view their documents as and when required.                                                                                                  On a different note, my MongoDb sits on an EC2 instance, will restricting inbound/outbound traffic, so as to disallow accessing mongodb from mongo client(allow accessing through ssh only), serve my purpose?

Comment: Pre-signed URLs should be generated in the back-end when rendering a page. Therefore, a user should never see an expired URL unless they left a page open for a long period, then tried to follow a link. As for your Mongo setup, I don't quite understand your question so I am unable to answer.